# How to use cases environment inside section or subsection command

Tags: sectioning, cases

How can I use a `cases` environment inside `\section` or `\subsection` directives, like this:

```
\section{$y(t) = \begin{cases} case1 \\ case  \end{cases}$}
```

With pdflatex I get:

> Use of \begin doesn't match its definition. ...begin{cases} case1 \
> case \end{cases}$}
>
> ...

Comment: that's a very weird heading!!!!, but you could use `\section[something reasonable for the page head]{$.....$}`

Comment: `\protect\begin` and `\protect\end` maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may achieve your typesetting objective using either a `cases` or an `array` environment; the latter will be spaced a bit more tightly. The trick, as pointed out by @egreg in a comment, is to `\protect` the `\begin` and `\end` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "cases" env.

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\medskip\hrule

\section{$y_t=\left\{ \protect\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} a_1 \\ a_2
              \protect\end{array} \right.$}

\section{$y_t=\protect\begin{cases} a_1 \\ a_2 
              \protect\end{cases}$}
\end{document}
```

If the math material in the section header has to be typeset in bold, just insert the directive `\boldmath` immediately before `$y_t=`.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

de gustibus non est disputandum

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\newsavebox\hmm
\savebox{\hmm}{$y(t) = \begin{cases} case1 \\ case  \end{cases}$}

\begin{document}


\section[something reasonable for the page head]{\usebox{\hmm}}


\end{document}
```